# use a variable as value in wordpress post__not_in

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have a variable called $excludes that has the following content: 12,32,345,676,677,733,980 can I use post__not_in like this:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'post__not_in' => $excludes ) );
```

To exclude the post id's found in $excludes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass an `array()` in `post__not_in` like `'post__not_in' => array(343, 493, 166),`

try :-

```
$str = '12,32,345,676,677,733,980';
$arr = explode(',', $str);
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'post__not_in' => $arr) );
```