# Display specific blog posts using ACF repeater in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I am trying to create simple repeter filed with ACF on my WordPress site. What I trying to get is to let admin display "Other interesting" blog posts at the bottom of the article.

So far I have created a loop with Wp_Query:

```
<?php
if( have_rows('featured') ): while( have_rows('featured') ) : the_row();    
?>  
    
<div class="container-fluid blog-container medium-container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 blog-one">

<?php
// Get ACF sub field
$get_ids = get_sub_field('article_id');
// Make them display with comma
$show_ids = implode(', ', $get_ids);

   // Featured blog list query
   $blog = new WP_Query( array(
   'posts_per_page' => 5,
   'order' => 'DESC',

   // Display post with specific ID using ACF repeater field inside array
   'post__in' => array($show_ids)
));

...
...
...

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

So the goal is to display numbers (posts ID's) included by admin on backend - liost them in array inside "post__in". But my code does not work. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: You don't need to implode id `$get_ids` contain an array.

Comment: What is Field type and Return format of sub field "article_id"

Comment: It's number. Should I change it into simple text field?

Comment: By imploding the IDs into a comma separated string, you are effectively passing `array('1,2,3')` to your query, and that is of course something completely different, than `array(1,2,3)`

Comment: So you are entering value like 1,2,3 in the text field ?

Comment: Yes. It is repeater field with numbes, like: 123, 500, 22 etc. (of course pure numbers, without commas. Each field contains one number). 

Now when I removed "implode", something has happened. I can see one article, but there are 4 repeater fields on my backend. I thing that WHILE & ENDWHILE is in wrong place.

Comment: Yes you have to fetch id's from sub field. Add into in one array and pass that array into your query your problem will be solved. You can look into this article for looping idea of ACF repeater field. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Comment: Yes Please remove the number filed and set text field and put ids comma separate like. 1,2,3 and then replace `implode` to `explode`

Comment: Right! This one works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118524/use-a-variable-as-value-in-wordpress-post-not-in

Comment: ACF has a post field type. You can configure it to accept and return multiple posts avoiding the need to write this sort of loop.

Answer (score 1):

Advanced Custom Fields has a post object field type. You can configure it to accept multiple posts which it will then return as an array of posts objects (WP_Post) for you. This avoids any need for looping through a repeater field to build the arguments for a query.

### Recommended Solution

Firstly, replace the repeater field with a post object field. Set the post type to post, allow null to true, and multiple to true.

You can then adapt your code to display those posts.

Example:

```
<?php if ( $featured_posts = get_field( 'featured' ) ) : ?>
    <div class="container-fluid blog-container medium-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 blog-one">
                <?php foreach ( $featured_posts as $post ) {
                    setup_postdata( $post );

                    // Do whatever you need to do to display the post here...
                } ?>
                . . .
<?php endif;
```

Documentation: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/

### Fixing Your Existing Code

If you'd instead prefer to fix the code you already have, you need to rethink the loop.

Each time you iterate over your repeater field, you'll go in and grab the ID that was entered (subfield) for the post. You need to collect all of those up first and then use that to build your query.

Example:

```
$posts_ids = [];

if ( have_rows( 'featured' ) ) : while( have_rows( 'featured' ) ) : the_row();
    $post_ids[] = get_sub_field( 'article_id' );
endwhile; endif;

// Let's drop any blank elements and force them all to integers.
$filtered_ids = array_map( 'intval', array_filter( $post_ids ) );

$blog_query = new WP_Query( [
    'post__in' => $filtered_ids,
] );
```

You could add some more checks, clean this up, etc. Either way you're still far better off letting ACF do this for you and opting for the recommended solution instead.